# Font being loaded from nowhere

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I've got a website that used to use the Roboto Google font. Since then the font was changed and the word roboto doesn't appear in a single line of code, yet, when visiting a specific page I can see the Roboto font being fetched from fonts.googleapis.com. The chrome network tab shows `initiator=other`

This doesn't only happen locally but also on my production enviroment. I'm using Rails 3.2.

Does anyone have any idea where this is coming from??

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: list all the files that you have in app/assets/stylesheets

Comment: What file should i be looking for. There's a lot of css files, but nothing font related and none of them reference Roboto

Comment: can you please paste the list of all files? does it have scaffold.css.scss in it?

Comment: Ok, so i found out the font is being loaded by google maps. My app does have scaffold.css in it though.. How could that make it load a font?
Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out the font was being loaded by google maps. Haven't found a way to disable it being loaded yet...